# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Timezone

Tags: ruby, timezone

I have installed timezone gem and in my view

```
<%= Timezone.names %>
```

and now im getting

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Timezone
```

is there anything to add?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: no still im getting error

Comment: did you see the answer I've provided? THere is no way you would still get the same error.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks its working now

Answer (score 1):

There is no such class as `Timezone`.

TO get all timezones you'll do:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

To get only the list of names, you can map them by `name`:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

Reference: [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).